# Using form_tag my instance variables are not saving when I try to search an API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, api, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a simple Rails app that will retrieve API data. My original intention were not to save the search to the database, which is why I used form_tag. My search works when I run in the console, but when I call `@results` or `@first_match`, it give me nil. Many thanks in advance.

**Actor Controller Method**

```
  def index
    @results = API::Topic.search([:actor])
    @first_match = @results.values.first
  end
```

**Actor Form**

```
= form_tag 'actors/show', method: :get do
  = text_field_tag "Actor"
  = submit_tag "Show me"
```

**Routes**

```
 RailsApp::Application.routes.draw do
   resources :actors
 end
```

---

**Update**

Since I am routing in the show method in the form. I was able to retrieve the variables in my show method in the controller. I don't know if this is the best way though.

```
  def show
    @results = API::Topic.search([:actor])
    @first_match = @results.values.first
  end
```

Comment: What gem are you using for search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you need to use `API::Topic.search(params[:actor])`

Comment: Thanks, I was able to retrieve them from the show method. It works, but I am not sure if that is the best way to retrieve them.